# Dissociation of H3PO4 and colligative properties

Tags: solutions, ions, boiling-point

> Which of the following solutions that have concentrations of $0.01\ \mathrm{M}$ show the highest elevation in boiling point and why?
>
> A) $\ce{NaCl}$
> B) $\ce{CaCl2}$
> C) $\ce{H3PO4 }$
> D) $\ce{C6H12O6}$ (glucose)

When dissolved in water, $\ce{H3PO4 }$ dissociates into 4 ions, which is more than any of the other compounds. Someone told me though, that because it's a weak-acid, it doesn't matter how many ions it has, and that $\ce{CaCl2}$ will still have the highest elevation boiling point. Is this true?

Comment: Phosphoric acid won’t dissociate further than $\ce{H3O+ + H2PO4-}$ in a standard aquaeous solution. That’s only two ions.

Comment: @Jan I've asked the same question on Quora(it wasn't active, that's why i asked it here). and this is what a chemist says : https://www.quora.com/Which-of-the-following-solutions-that-have-concentrations-of-0-01m-show-the-highest-elevation-in-boiling-point-Why

Comment: That person has not the slightest of clues what he is talking about.

Comment: If you want, you can write up a self-answer. The preferred Stack Exchange way of showing that you found a solution to your problem ;)

Comment: Hey you need to know the degree of dissociation $\alpha$ to answer this question most accurately.